# How to append an attribute to an existing xml using stax parser

Tags: java, stax

I want to appened an attribute to an existing xml using stax parse. Please suggest.

Below is the snippnet code which I need to appened.

```
<un:UtranCell id="RNC17-1-1">
```

It as to look like as follow after appending

```
<un:UtranCell id="RNC17-1-1" modifier="delete">
```

Below is snippnet code i tried. but i am failied to add the attribute

```
try {               
      File fXmlFile = new File("/home/xgeoraj/bcgImportFiles/imports/UtranCell.xml");
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
      System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
      NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("un:UtranCell");
      for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
          System.out.println("UtranCell id is: " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the XML file in which i need to add it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd" xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd" xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd" xmlns:es="EricssonSpecificAttributes.14.02.xsd">
    <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" vendorName="Ericsson"/>
    <configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
        <xn:SubNetwork id="ONRM_ROOT_MO_R">
            <xn:SubNetwork id="RNC17">
                <xn:MeContext id="RNC17">
                    <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                        <un:RncFunction id="1">
                            <un:UtranCell id="RNC17-1-1" modifier="delete">
```

Comment: I dont have code.. i need code to appened modifier="delete" to the existing xml file. Please help

Comment: I actually didn't mean source code in this case, but earlier the "xml code" was missing too. Either way it may help us to help you if you provide some source code of attempts that you have tried so far as SO is about asking for help when your own attempts have failed. Taken from the SO help: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: So, if you include an attempted solution, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have added my code snippet. hope you can view it.

Comment: You need to double-check that your code is actually viewable after your edits. The java code formatting was not so good (but you got help from @Scobal) and the same with the xml example (but that is also fixed).

Comment: Do i need to add the code again?

Comment: No, with the nice help of the SO community it is all there now. I hope you get the help you need.

Comment: hi Daniel, i havent got any solution yet.

Comment: I have never used StAX so I wouldn't be the best to help you. I was mainly trying to help you to get your question arranged so that it would be more likely for you to get help from someone who knows StAX. Now I had a quick look in the StAX api docs and I can't see you using any StAX classes.

Comment: yes correct! i havent used stax. i used DOM parser. i need how it can be done using stax .

Comment: using Python also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an attribute to the element you have retrieved which is what I think you want to do is done by setting an element. taking out the if-statement.

```
if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
    System.out.println("UtranCell id is: " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
    eElement.setAttribute("modifier", "delete"); // <-- This is the added line
}
```

For a reference see the [javadoc for Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html).